# Посчитать кол-во единиц в десятичном двузначном числе

Tags: c++builder, числа

я не знаю какой командой(-ами) сделать так чтобы программа высчитывала единицы в числе.

[image: сама программа]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

способ 1:

преобразовать число в строку и последовательно найти все "1" в строке

для этого понадобится работать с массивом (строка - это массив символов, заканчивающихся 0)

```
#include <string> 

const int num = 1234321; // для примера
std::string str = std::to_string(num);

int count = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < str.size(); index ++)
    if (str[index] == '1')
        count ++;
```

способ 2:

можно последовательно вычислять остатки от деления числа на 10 и считать 1:

```
const int num = 1234321; // для примера

int count = 0;
int tmp = num;
while (tmp != 0) {
    if (tmp % 10 == 1)
        count++;

    tmp /= 10;
}
```

Comment: " tmp " - какую функцию выполняет?
Просто я только  с арифметическими операциями и математическими функциями знаком, и мне бы на основе этого бы написать программу.

Comment: @Tadidemirov, `tmp` - это переменная, значение которой мы будем постепенно сводить к `0` - например у нас есть `tmp = 121`, делим по модулю на `10` - получаем остаток `1`, т.е. `+1` в копилку, делим `tmp` на 10, получаем `tmp = 12`, делаем следующую итерацию - делим по модулю на `10` - получаем остаток `2`, в копилку ничего, делим `tmp` на `10`, получаем `tmp = 1`, делаем следующую итерацию - делим по модулю на `10`, получаем остаток `1`, в копилку еще `+1`, делим `tmp` на `10`, получаем `tmp = 0`, цикл закончен. Т.е. мы как бы сдвигаем целое число направо, избавляясь от последней цифры